# Pandas: Copy fields in duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like this:

| email | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | attr4 | attr5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc@mymail.com | ANC | nan | LKH | nan | nan |
| abc@mymail.com | nan | BCH | LKH | nan | KTH |
| abc@mymail.com | ANC | BCH | LKH | UTY | KTH |

My key column for duplicates is `email`. I want to copy attr fields to one another such that the resulting table doesn't have `nan` and all the rows look identical.

| email | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | attr4 | attr5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc@mymail.com | ANC | BCH | LKH | UTY | KTH |
| abc@mymail.com | ANC | BCH | LKH | UTY | KTH |
| abc@mymail.com | ANC | BCH | LKH | UTY | KTH |

Data:

```
{'email': ['abc@mymail.com', 'abc@mymail.com', 'abc@mymail.com'],
 'attr1': ['ANC', nan, 'ANC'],
 'attr2': [nan, 'BCH', 'BCH'],
 'attr3': ['LKH', 'LKH', 'LKH'],
 'attr4': [nan, nan, 'UTY'],
 'attr5': [nan, 'KTH', 'KTH']}
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to `groupby` "email" and transform `first` (since `first` skips NaN values and transform makes `first` outcome align with the original DataFrame) and update `df` with it:

```
df.update(df.groupby('email').transform('first'))
```

Another option is `groupby` + `bfill`:

```
df.update(df.groupby('email').bfill())
```

Output:

```
            email attr1 attr2 attr3 attr4 attr5
0  abc@mymail.com   ANC   BCH   LKH   UTY   KTH
1  abc@mymail.com   ANC   BCH   LKH   UTY   KTH
2  abc@mymail.com   ANC   BCH   LKH   UTY   KTH
```

EDIT:
The above answer pretty much solves the problem. But in case you don't know that you rows needs to be backfilled or forwardfilled you have to apply to both methods in order to avoid NaNs in some rows. Just do

```
df.update(df.groupby('email').bfill())
df.update(df.groupby('email').ffill())
```